# Upsert: Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an **upsert** query in mongoose which was working in 3.8 but, after I've upgraded to 4 I'm getting

```
Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array
```

this is my model:

```
var ActivitySchema = new Schema({
    owner:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    sequence:{
        type:Number,
        default: 0
    },
    items:[
        {
            posted:{
                type:Date,
                default:Date.now
            },
            verb:{
                type: String,
                enum: [ 'leave','join','support','share','comment', 'upload', 'rate','message','update', 'signup']
            },
            text:{
                type: String,
            },
            reference: {
                objectType:{
                    type: String,
                    enum: [ 'document','element','process', 'project', 'user']
                },
                refObj:{}
            }
        }]
});
```

the upsert:

```
Activity.update({
        $and:[
            {'owner':ownerId},
            {'sequence':bucket}
        ]},
        {
            $push:{items:newItem }
        },
        {
            upsert:true
        }).execAsync();
```

and the data is like this:

```
//newItem
{ verb: 'join',
  text: 'Has joined to a team',
  reference: 
   { 
     refObj: { teamId: '56269fd1e923cc7a7b46dcf8', name: 'test1' },
     objectType: 'user' 
   } 
}
```

ownerId is a mongoId like 56251c01507dc35423694118
and bucket is an integer 0

is there any breacking change that I need to be aware?, I've been looking and I haven't found yet related, any other workaround, solution?

Comment: You don't need to use a $and in the query. Multiple fields in a query are automatically treated as AND.

Comment: The definition of a major semver version is that there are breaking changes :) For a full list, see https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem, if it is the same case then make sure all fields type are matched to the `mongoose.model('yourModel')`.
Hopes that helps.